# Select count field of rows that are related to another table

Tags: sql

I'm struggling with this issue from a long time and don't know how to solve it. It's hard for me to describe, so please be patient. There are two tables:

Table "Users"

```
UserId PK
Gender
```

Table "Forms"

```
FormId PK
UserId1 FK
UserId2 FK
Type
```

Forms are always related to two users, but not all users have related forms. Now I want to count specified gender only of those users, who have related forms.

So as a result, I want to have sth. like this:

```
# |  Gender | GenderCount
1 |  male   |     43
2 |  female |     12
3 |  trans  |     2
```

I tried the following SQL-Script but the result isn't distinct (the sum of all GenderCount is greater then the actual number of users)

```
SELECT u.Gender AS 'Gender', COUNT(u.Gender) AS 'GenderCount' 
FROM Users u, Forms f 
WHERE ((f.UserId1 = u.UserId) 
    OR (f.UserId2 = u.UserId)) 
AND (Type = 'Foo') 
GROUP BY Gender 
ORDER BY GenderCount 
DESC
```

Any tips to solve this?

Comment: Why not COUNT(DISTINCT u.Gender) ?

Comment: @WillPalmer If I would use COUNT(DISTINCT u.Gender) i would get `male => 1, female => 1, trans => 1`

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. You want to know how many of each gender answered any form, but you want to ensure that each user is only counted once, correct?

Comment: @WillPalmer Correct. Thank you for clearing up my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at what you want:

- How many of each gender answered any form?
- Note: each user should only be counted once, no matter how many forms they've filled out.

Phrased like this, the answer becomes fairly obvious, at least in pseudo-code:

```
SELECT
    u.Gender,
    COUNT(u.Gender)
FROM
    Users u
WHERE
    [User has answered a form]
GROUP BY
    u.Gender
```

The easiest way to determine if a user has answered a form depends on the specific flavour of SQL being used. You'll need to use a subquery. There are a couple of options for how to access it.

`IN` is the most common method:

```
SELECT
    u.Gender        Gender,
    COUNT(u.Gender) GenderCount
FROM
    Users u
WHERE
    u.id IN (
        SELECT f.UserId1 user_id FROM Forms f WHERE Type = 'Foo'
        UNION
        SELECT f.UserId2 user_id FROM Forms f WHERE Type = 'Foo'
    )
GROUP BY
    Gender
ORDER BY
    GenderCount DESC
```

Where available, `EXISTS` is more natural to read, and is sometimes faster:

```
SELECT
    u.Gender        Gender,
    COUNT(u.Gender) GenderCount
FROM
    Users u
WHERE
    EXISTS(
        SELECT '1'
        FROM Forms f
        WHERE
            (f.UserId1 = u.id OR f.UserId2 = u.id)
            AND Type = 'Foo'
    )
GROUP BY
    Gender
ORDER BY
    GenderCount DESC
```

Regarding speed: The query optimiser will often convert `IN` to `EXISTS` where possible, to avoid selecting extra rows unnecessarily. However, the use of multiple columns necessitates either an `OR` or a `UNION`, so it may be pretty even in this case. ie: neither `OR` nor `UNION` play nicely with indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Skip the join which is generating multiple rows per user:

```
SELECT Gender, COUNT(Gender) AS 'GenderCount' 
FROM Users
WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId1 FROM Forms WHERE Type = 'Foo' 
                 UNION 
                 SELECT UserId2 FROM Forms WHERE Type = 'Foo')
GROUP BY Gender 
ORDER BY GenderCount DESC
```

Or if you prefer to avoid a UNION (which is perfectly valid in this scenario BTW) you can use OR like this:

```
SELECT Gender, COUNT(Gender) AS 'GenderCount' 
FROM Users
WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId1 FROM Forms WHERE Type = 'Foo')
   OR UserId IN (SELECT UserId2 FROM Forms WHERE Type = 'Foo')
GROUP BY Gender 
ORDER BY GenderCount DESC
```

As others have pointed out, there are ways to do this using a JOIN as well.  However, a JOIN adds needless complexity for the DBMS engine as it will first need to match up the rows, and then reduce to DISTINCT values.

Comment: You can avoid the union and use OR instead.  All comes down to the same thing in the end...

Comment: @PinnyM Simply replacing `UNION` with `OR` seem to result an incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR' and ')'

Comment: @PinnyM Your first answer only seem to work, if I remove `FormUsers`. Is this suggested as an alias?

Comment: Correct - it was meant as an alias which is not valid SQL for a non-joining subquery.  Fixed, and added code for the OR option.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because your script results the right number of gender. However Will's method using EXISTS seems smarter, because it I don't have to specify the `WHERE` clause twice and it might be slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u1.Gender AS 'Gender', COUNT(*) AS 'GenderCount'
FROM
    Users u1 
        INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT u.UserId
    FROM 
        Users u
            INNER JOIN Forms f ON ((f.UserId1 = u.UserId) 
                                OR (f.UserId2 = u.UserId))
                                AND (f.Type = 'Foo')) T ON T.UserId = u1.UserId
GROUP BY Gender 
ORDER BY GenderCount DESC
```

Comment: After correcting your script in line 1 to `SELECT u1.Gender` it seems to work.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because your script results the right number of gender. However Will's method using `EXISTS` seems smarter, because it avoids `DISTINCT`, which causes an extra load on the sql server.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
count(distinct u.UserId)
```

that way users only get counted once: count(distinct field_name) counts the number of unique values contained in field_name, so counting distinct on the primary key gives you the number of unique users, which is what you're looking for.

Also, instead of joining, you probably would be better off using an in clause like this

```
select Gender, count(distinct UserId) as GenderCount
from Users
where u.UserId in (select UserId1 from Forms) or u.UserId in (select UserId2 from Forms)
```

It's probably also going to be slightly faster.

Comment: Same here: Using your script results a sum of gender count which is by far greater then the actual number of users